# feathers-client ionic2 - Cannot find module 'events' - only in Windows10

Tags: windows, ionic2, feathersjs

I am building a featherjs using socketIO backend with an Ionic2 frontend.

This code seems to be working fine in an Ubuntu environment. However I'm trying to setup a dev environment on windows 10, and getting the following error.

I have previously setup typings for feathers-client using the instructions found here:
https://berndsgn.ch/angular2-and-feathersjs/

(again, this is working in Ubuntu but not in Windows10)

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\mickt_000\Documents\tumble\tumble-app>ionic serve
Starting app-scripts server: --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --address 0.0.0.0 - Ctrl+C to cancel
[09:58:38]  watch started ...
[09:58:38]  build dev started ...
[09:58:38]  clean started ...
[09:58:38]  clean finished in 2 ms
[09:58:38]  copy started ...
[09:58:38]  transpile started ...
[09:58:41]  typescript: ...rs/mickt_000/Documents/tumble/tumble-app/node_modules/feathers-client/index.d.ts, line: 1
            Cannot find module 'events'.

       L1:  import events = require('events');

[09:58:41]  transpile failed
[09:58:41]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[09:58:41]  copy finished in 3.52 s
[09:58:41]  watch ready in 3.61 s
```

Some additional info

```
C:\Users\mickt_000\Documents\tumble\tumble-app>npm install --save events
Tumble-App@ C:\Users\mickt_000\Documents\tumble\tumble-app
+-- events@1.1.1
+-- feathers@2.1.2
| `-- events@1.1.1  deduped
`-- feathers-client@2.2.0
  `-- feathers@2.1.1
    `-- events@1.1.1  deduped

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular@1.0.0 requires a peer of @ionic/app-scripts@^1.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN The package @types/socket.io-client is included as both a dev and production dependency.

C:\Users\mickt_000\Documents\tumble\tumble-app>npm -v
4.5.0

C:\Users\mickt_000\Documents\tumble\tumble-app>node -v
v6.10.3
```

I have also tried reinstalling cordova ionic and also performed npm clean cache.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange. Tried deleting npm_modules/ and running npm install again?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well. Same result unfortunately.